# Why am I getting 100 Mbps, when my internet plan allows 250 Mbps?

Tags: ethernet, speed

I couple weeks ago, I upgraded my internet to a 250 mbps plan.

This plan has been very good so far, but I am only getting 100 mbps from my PC, which is connected via ethernet. I am getting 250 mbps everywhere else in my house through wifi.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your house network is Gigabit? Especially the switch/router

Comment: Do both the router and your PC have Gigabit Ethernet? And are you using the correct GbE-rated cable?

Comment: Is your ISP a cable provider? You may need to upgrade your cable modem. I had an 8x4 modem that I thought was good to 343Mbps, turned out the way the ISP provisions channels. I need to order a 16x8 channel modem for the 250Mbps speed tier.   Who is your ISP?

Comment: What is the spec of your desktop Ethernet NIC..?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have Gb ports on your computer/notebook/device.
- Check if your home Switch supports 1Gbps (if you have one installed).
- Check if your router and/or modem has both WAN and LAN gigabit ports.
- Ask your provider if they actually applied the new speed plan (some sometimes forget that part).
- If you confirm all the above open a ticket with them and ask them to come and check the problem.